# Derivatives of exponential functions

Tags: derivatives

For what values of m does the function y = $Ae^{mt}$ satisfy the following equation?
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + \frac{dy}{dx} - 6y = 0$

I tried taking the first and second derivative of the function, but I got stuck there.
$\frac{dy}{dx} = Ate^{mt}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = At^2e^{mt}$

$-6y = -6Ae^{mt}$

Comment: There's no $x$ in your function.  Did you mean dt instead of dx?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#Homogeneous_equations_with_constant_coefficients

Comment: no the questions is in terms of dx... not dt

Comment: okay thanks @SujaanKunalan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's find $y'$ and $y''$.

$y=Ae^{mx}$ is given.

$\frac{dy}{dx}=A\cdot me^{mx}$.

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=A\cdot m\cdot me^{mx}=Am^2e^{mx}$.

Now we plug these into the differential equation above.

$Am^2e^{mx}+Ame^{mx}-6Ae^{mx}=0\\
\implies Ae^{mx}(m^2+m-6)=0\\
\implies Ae^{mx}(m+3)(m-2)=0$

So what values of $m$ would make the last equation equal to $0$?

Well, $Ae^{mx}$ can't be zero (unless $A=0$), which just leaves:

$m+3=0\implies m=-3$ and $m-2=0\implies m=2$.

Hence the values of $m$ which would satisfy the differential equation are $m=2$ or $m=-3$.

Comment: It's wrong, if he indeed meant $y=Ae^{mt}$. However, if he meant $y=Ae^{mx}$, and the $t$ was a typo, this is right.

Answer (score 0):

If you did indeed mean $y=Ae^{mx}$, then we can substitute
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=Ame^{mx}\\
\implies \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}=Am^2e^{mx}$$
Substituting gives
$$Am^2e^{mx}+Ame^{mx}-6Ae^{mx}=0\\
\implies\text{ For nonzero $A$, }m^2+m-6=0\\
\implies m=\dfrac{-1\pm\sqrt{25}}{2}$$